# Why is ARSession restarted session slowly?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I am using ARKit for my AR application. I need frequently start and stop ARSession.
But when I restart ARSession after stopping it is going to normal state slowly then initial start. It means restarting ARSession is given more time then initial starting.
I tried to recreate ARSession instead of restarting, but it is failed always.

Here is my code:

```
private let session = ARSession()

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  setupVM()
  setupARSession()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  restartARSession()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
  session.pause()
}

private func startARSession() {
  let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
  configuration.frameSemantics = .sceneDepth

  session.run(configuration)
}

private func restartARSession() {
  if let configuration = session.configuration {
    session.run(configuration, options: .resetSceneReconstruction)
  }
}
```

How do I restart ARSession faster?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing `sessionShouldAttemptRelocalization` on your ARSession delegate. If you return false like below, you're assuming the user is in the same location. [More options can be found in the documentation for sessionShouldAttemptRelocalization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionobserver/2941046-sessionshouldattemptrelocalizati).

```
func sessionShouldAttemptRelocalization(_ session: ARSession) -> Bool {
  return false
}
```

(source: Ask Apple event October 17-21)